# How to use variadic templates and template metaprogramming to accept different type as input

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, fizzbuzz

How to use variadic templates and template metaprogramming to accept different type as input?

```
//This template takes variable number of c++ char and add'\0' 
//to the end to mimic the c_str() inbuilt function 
template<char ...Cs> struct listChar 
{
    constexpr std::array<char, 1 + sizeof...(Cs)> cTypeStr() 
    {
        return { {Cs..., '\0'} };
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto temp1 = listChar<'C','H','A','N','G','E'>::cTypeStr();//This works
    //auto temp2 = listChar<"Change">::cTypeStr(); // Do not work
    //auto temp3 = listChar<"Change",'C','H','A','N','G','E'>::cTypeStr();//Do not work 
    cout << "Output: \n" << spStr.data();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Solving a particular programming test or challenge problem is rarely a good fit as a question on this site.  Do you have something more specific you'd like to ask?

Comment: @John Zwinck if you can  just tell me how to loop over N times using above logic it would be helpful.

Comment: I tried to loop from this code -> using type = typename CharList< N, FizzBuzzSeq<N-1>::type>; But it is giving compiler error

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to build the string at compile time, here's a much simpler approach that doesn't involve variadic templates or type traits:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <int N, bool fizz, bool buzz>
struct _FizzBuzz;

template <int N>
struct FizzBuzz : _FizzBuzz<N, N % 3 == 0, N % 5 == 0>
{
};

template <>
struct FizzBuzz<1>
{
    static std::string str()
    {
        return "1";
    }
};

template <int N>
struct _FizzBuzz<N, true, true>
{
    static std::string str()
    {
        return FizzBuzz<N - 1>::str() + "\nFizzBuzz";
    }

};

template <int N>
struct _FizzBuzz<N, true, false>
{
    static std::string str()
    {
        return FizzBuzz<N - 1>::str() + "\nFizz";
    }

};

template <int N>
struct _FizzBuzz<N, false, true>
{
    static std::string str()
    {
        return FizzBuzz<N - 1>::str() + "\nBuzz";
    }

};

template <int N>
struct _FizzBuzz<N, false, false>
{
    static std::string str()
    {
        return FizzBuzz<N - 1>::str() + "\n" + std::to_string(N);
    }

};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto spStr = FizzBuzz<47>::str();
    std::cout << "Your Output: \n" << spStr;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My requirement needs to build the string at compile time.